# How to prevent our service from running in Modern Standby

Tags: .net, windows, service, sleep, standby

Our Program is running as a System Service in Windows installed using Topshelf. We have detected that our Service is running in small allocated intervals during Modern Standby when a comptaible device (Surface laptop) lid is closed. We are getting major issues with files getting corrupted with NULL symbols when our app is writing and it's CPU time is revoked (we think).

Does anyone know how to tell Windows not to run our Service during Standby mode? We are not able to utilize this feature and it is only causing us headaches.

We know that there are events Windows should be sending us when we enter and leave modern standby, but those are broken in Topshelf right now it seems.